# Sizing WPF windows automatically

Tags: wpf, layout, window

When designing WPF dialog windows in the XAML designer (that are not manually resizeable by the user), the windows automatically resize to fit their content, and everything is fine. But when I run my app, the windows become huge and there's a lot of empty space.

I know this is a "feature" of WPF that can be "fixed" by setting the `SizeToContent` tag, but another issue arises when I do this: If the window contains a textbox, for instance, and the user enters data that overflows the visible area, the window will stretch to accommodate it. This happens with listboxes, treeviews, you name it.

All I want is for Visual Studio to figure out the ideal window size that it shows me at design time, then set the window to be that size at runtime, and don't change the size after that. It seems like this should be an easy thing to do.

Edit: Figured out part of the problem: I have controls set up in a grid, and the column's width is set to "Auto" which is why everything is resizing.

Answer (score 2):

Use **View Box**

The ViewBox is a very useful control in WPF. If does nothing more than scale to fit the content to the available size. It does not resize the content, but it transforms it. This means that also all text sizes and line widths were scaled. Its about the same behavior as if you set the Stretch property on an Image or Path to Uniform.

Although it can be used to fit any type of control, it's often used for 2D graphics, or to fit a scalable part of a user interface into an screen area.

```
<Viewbox>
<Enter your code/>
</Viewbox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the window's height and width to Auto.  Also, remove the SizeToContent attribute.  This should fix it.

Comment: That's how I have it set now, actually.

Comment: So you don't have the SizeToContent?

Comment: Right, it's set to its automatic value, "Manual".

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that this is this is something which is commonly requested so it's probably not easy to do, one method i can think of would be starting with automatic `SizeToContent` and handling the `Loaded` event and setting:

```
Height = ActualHeight;
Width = ActualWidth;
SizeToContent = System.Windows.SizeToContent.Manual;
```